# How can I make text get smaller in order to stay on one line?

Tags: html

I have a `<td>` the gets populated with text when a user fills out a field. If the text the user enters is bigger than my 200px wide , it wraps around and messes up my design. Is there a way to make the text get smaller in order to fit on one line instead of wrapping around?

Comment: Not without Javascript (and not easily, either). You can `overflow: hidden` I suppose, but that will just hide what is longer than the element.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can't `overflow: hidden` a `td`. You could a `p` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/aB9BX/

Comment: Not only would it be difficult to do, it would probably be really annoying to users (ever-shrinking text will quickly become altogether unreadable). It's likely a better idea to work out your design such that it accommodates wrapping the regular sized text (e.g. by using a `textarea` which can scroll vertically)

Comment: You can do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/vWmFp/ Or use a tooltip plugin to show the text inside (I assume).

Comment: Thank you all, I think you're right @KenWayneVanderLinde, it would be better to adjust my design. JaredFarrish, thanks for the jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you set maximum length of string, if it over the limit, just cut the text and add "...
" text . place title in tag , so it can read completly when mouse over .

> example : blabla bla
>   bla bla ...

just short in visual text, and use title

Answer (score 1):

You can use ellipsis, this is CSS3 property, [more info about this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

```
td p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: @oobie11 Sorry if you dont try to work with CSS3 on the project.