# How to make the text be smaller when overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the text to  stay within one line,
so I want it to become smaller if there is a overflow.

I **dont** want to use `ellipsis` like the answer
that he ([How can I make text get smaller in order to stay on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550460/how-can-i-make-text-get-smaller-in-order-to-stay-on-one-line)) got.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#button').click(function() 
    {
    var current_size = $('#content_to_be_resized').css('font-size');
    var new_size = parseFloat(current_size) - 3;
    $('#content_to_be_resized').animate({fontSize: new_size}, 250);
    });
});
```

Suppose you click on a button you get you current size of the text and you make a new size using the parseFloat which actually parses a string and returns a floating point number, so in 20px – parseFloat() will return 20.